# ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor (saving autoencoder's decoder)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I built my CNN Autoencoder in Keras. My data (not provided) are 2000 samples of 501 points. I split my data in 1500 samples for training, 500 for testing. I want to SAVE the decoder part. This is my code:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Lambda, Activation, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, UpSampling1D, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import copy


# read data
data = # some data
# shuffle
import random
random.seed(4)
random.shuffle(data)

# split train/test
X_train = data[:1500]
X_test = data[1500:]

# reshaping for CNN
X_training = np.reshape(X_train, [1500, 501, 1])
X_testing = np.reshape(X_test, [500, 501, 1])

# normalize input
X_mean = X_training.mean()
X_training -= X_mean
X_std = X_training.std()
X_training /= X_std

X_testing -= X_mean
X_testing /= X_std


## MODEL ###
# ENCODER
input_sig = Input(batch_shape=(None,501,1))
x = Conv1D(256,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(input_sig)
x1 = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
x2 = Conv1D(32,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(x1)
x3 = MaxPooling1D(2)(x2)
flat = Flatten()(x3)
encoded = Dense(32,activation = 'tanh')(flat)

# DECODER 
x2_ = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(x3)
x1_ = UpSampling1D(2)(x2_)
x_ = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(x1_)
upsamp = UpSampling1D(2)(x_)
flat = Flatten()(upsamp)
decoded = Dense(501)(flat)
decoded = Reshape((501,1))(decoded)

autoencoder = Model(input_sig, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])


### TRAINING ###
epochs = 50
batch_size = 100
validation_split = 0.2
# train the model
history = autoencoder.fit(x = X_training, y = X_training,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_split=validation_split)

# Decoder
decoder = Model(inputs=encoded, outputs=decoded, name='decoder')
# save decoder
decoder.save('decoder.hdf5')
```

The error I am getting is

```
W1013 12:08:17.131777 140693540189952 network.py:1619] Model inputs must come from `tf.keras.Input` (thus holding past layer metadata), they cannot be the output of a previous non-Input layer. Here, a tensor specified as input to "decoder" was not an Input tensor, it was generated by layer dense.
Note that input tensors are instantiated via `tensor = tf.keras.Input(shape)`.
The tensor that caused the issue was: dense/Tanh:0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Autoenc_CNN_ISOTROPIC_oscillations.py", line 191, in <module>
    decoder = Model(inputs=encoded, outputs=decoded, name='decoder')
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 122, in __init__
    super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 138, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 456, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 284, in _init_graph_network
    self.inputs, self.outputs)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1814, in _map_graph_network
    str(layers_with_complete_input))
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 501, 1), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

How should I adjust the line

```
decoder = Model(inputs=encoded, outputs=decoded, name='decoder')
```

so that the inputs are such that I manage to save the trained decoder?

Comment: See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#all_models_are_callable_just_like_layers) on the Tensorflow site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, your `encoded` in `Model` is not an `Input` layer, which former expects - and your decoder definition disconnects the Input-Output graph. To this end, you'll need to reconstruct the decoder separately for the decoder model, as the autoencoder's (AE) decoder takes AE's encoder layer output as input, whereas the separate decoder model will *not* be connected to AE's E layers.

Below is a cleaned up code defining both autoencoder and decoder and saving both.

```py
## ENCODER
encoder_input = Input(batch_shape=(None,501,1))
x  = Conv1D(256,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(encoder_input)
x  = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
x  = Conv1D(32,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(x)
x  = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
_x = Flatten()(x)
encoded = Dense(32,activation = 'tanh')(_x)

## DECODER (autoencoder)
y = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(x)
y = UpSampling1D(2)(y)
y = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(y)
y = UpSampling1D(2)(y)
y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(501)(y)
decoded = Reshape((501,1))(y)

autoencoder = Model(encoder_input, decoded)
autoencoder.save('autoencoder.hdf5')
```

```py
## DECODER (independent)
decoder_input = Input(batch_shape=K.int_shape(x))  # import keras.backend as K
y = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(decoder_input)
y = UpSampling1D(2)(y)
y = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(y)
y = UpSampling1D(2)(y)
y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(501)(y)
decoded = Reshape((501,1))(y)

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoded)
decoder.save('decoder.hdf5')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to allow me to train the autoencoder, and save some `encoded` in your notation, then save the autoencoder (and decoder), and load the trained decoder, so that I can feed it with some other values of `encoded` that I independently find somewhere else?

Comment: @johnhenry I think you meant feed it with other values of `encoded`, as `decoded` is already the output of the model; if so, yes - you train the AE, then store E's outputs somewhere, and feed them directly to trained decoder. This'll require loading AE's weights onto the independent decoder, which can be done, but is matter of a separate question. If you open such a question, feel free to mention me ('@') in a comment, I should be able to assist

Comment: @johnhenry and by the way, never use `'accuracy'` as a metric with `loss='mse'`; for regression, "accuracy" is not defined (you can only measure the 'closeness' of predictions vs. labels; if you measured accuracy as with classification, it'd always be close to zero as you'd have to match labels, which are float32 real-numbers, exactly)

Comment: thanks so much, please see 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364974/keras-feed-new-central-features-to-saved-decoder-from-cnn-autoencoder