# How to load trained autoencoder weights for decoder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I have a CNN 1d autoencoder which has a dense central layer. I would like to train this Autoencoder and save its model. I would also like to save the decoder part, with this goal: feed some central features (calculated independently) to the trained and loaded decoder, to see what are the images of these independently calculated features through the decoder.

```
## ENCODER
encoder_input = Input(batch_shape=(None,501,1))
x  = Conv1D(256,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(encoder_input)
x  = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
x  = Conv1D(32,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(x)
x  = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
_x = Flatten()(x)
encoded = Dense(32,activation = 'tanh')(_x)

## DECODER (autoencoder)
y = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(x)
y = UpSampling1D(2)(y)
y = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(y)
y = UpSampling1D(2)(y)
y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(501)(y)
decoded = Reshape((501,1))(y)

autoencoder = Model(encoder_input, decoded)
autoencoder.save('autoencoder.hdf5')

## DECODER (independent)
decoder_input = Input(batch_shape=K.int_shape(x))  # import keras.backend as K
y = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(decoder_input)
y = UpSampling1D(2)(y)
y = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(y)
y = UpSampling1D(2)(y)
y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(501)(y)
decoded = Reshape((501,1))(y)

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoded)
decoder.save('decoder.hdf5')
```

EDIT:

Just to make sure that it is clear, I first need to JOIN `encoded` and the first `y`, in the sense that `y` has to take `encoded` as input. Once this is done, I need a way to load a trained decoder and replace `encoded` with some new central features, which I will feed my decoder with.

EDIT following answer:

I implemented the suggestion, see code below

```
## ENCODER
encoder_input = Input(batch_shape=(None,501,1))
x  = Conv1D(256,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(encoder_input)
x  = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
x  = Conv1D(32,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(x)
x  = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
_x = Flatten()(x)
encoded = Dense(32,activation = 'tanh')(_x)

## DECODER (autoencoder)
encoded = Reshape((32,1))(encoded)
y = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(encoded)
y = UpSampling1D(2)(y)
y = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(y)
y = UpSampling1D(2)(y)
y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(501)(y)
decoded = Reshape((501,1))(y)

autoencoder = Model(encoder_input, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
epochs = 10
batch_size = 100
validation_split = 0.2
# train the model
history = autoencoder.fit(x = training, y = training,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_split=validation_split)
autoencoder.save_weights('autoencoder_weights.h5')


## DECODER (independent)
decoder_input = Input(batch_shape=K.int_shape(encoded))  # import keras.backend as K
y = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_1')(decoder_input)
y = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_1')(y)
y = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_2')(y)
y = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_2')(y)
y = Flatten(name='decod_flatten')(y)
y = Dense(501, name='decod_dense1')(y)
decoded = Reshape((501,1), name='decod_reshape')(y)

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoded)
decoder.save_weights('decoder_weights.h5')


encoder = Model(inputs=encoder_input, outputs=encoded, name='encoder')
features = encoder.predict(training) # features
np.savetxt('features.txt', np.squeeze(features))

predictions = autoencoder.predict(training)
predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)
np.savetxt('predictions.txt', predictions)
```

Then I open another file and I do

```
import h5py
import keras.backend as K

def load_weights(model, filepath):
    with h5py.File(filepath, mode='r') as f:
        file_layer_names = [n.decode('utf8') for n in f.attrs['layer_names']]
        model_layer_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]

        weight_values_to_load = []
        for name in file_layer_names:
            if name not in model_layer_names:
                print(name, "is ignored; skipping")
                continue
            g = f[name]
            weight_names = [n.decode('utf8') for n in g.attrs['weight_names']]

            weight_values = []
            if len(weight_names) != 0:
                weight_values = [g[weight_name] for weight_name in weight_names]
            try:
                layer = model.get_layer(name=name)
            except:
                layer = None
            if layer is not None:
                symbolic_weights = (layer.trainable_weights + 
                                    layer.non_trainable_weights)
                if len(symbolic_weights) != len(weight_values):
                    print('Model & file weights shapes mismatch')
                else:
                    weight_values_to_load += zip(symbolic_weights, weight_values)

        K.batch_set_value(weight_values_to_load)

## DECODER (independent)
decoder_input = Input(batch_shape=(None,32,1))
y = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh',padding='valid',name='decod_conv1d_1')(decoder_input)
y = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_1')(y)
y = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_2')(y)
y = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_2')(y)
y = Flatten(name='decod_flatten')(y)
y = Dense(501, name='decod_dense1')(y)
decoded = Reshape((501,1), name='decod_reshape')(y)

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoded)
#decoder.save_weights('decoder_weights.h5')

load_weights(decoder, 'autoencoder_weights.h5')

# Read autoencoder
decoder.summary()

# read encoded features
features = np.loadtxt('features.txt'.format(batch_size, epochs))
features = np.reshape(features, [1500,32,1])

# evaluate loaded model on features
prediction = decoder.predict(features)



autoencoderpredictions = np.loadtxt('predictions.txt'.format(batch_size, epochs))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, figsize=(10,20))
for i in range(5):
        ax[i].plot(prediction[100*i], color='blue', label='Decoder')
        ax[i].plot(autoencoderpredictions[100*i], color='red', label='AE')
        ax[i].set_xlabel('Time components', fontsize='x-large')
        ax[i].set_ylabel('Amplitude', fontsize='x-large')
        ax[i].set_title('Seismogram n. {:}'.format(1500+100*i+1), fontsize='x-large')
        ax[i].legend(fontsize='x-large')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)
plt.close()
```

`prediction` and `autoencoderpredictions` do not agree. It seems as if `prediction` is just small noise, whereas `autoencoder predictions` has reasonable values.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to: (1) save weights of AE (autoencoder); (2) load weights file; (3) deserialize the file and assign only those weights that are compatible with the new model (decoder).

- (1): `.save` does include the weights, but with an extra deserialization step that's spared by using `.save_weights` instead. Also, `.save` saves optimizer state and model architecture, latter which is irrelevant for your new decoder
- (2): `load_weights` by default attempts to assign *all* saved weights, which won't work

Code below accomplishes (3) (and remedies (2)) as follows:

1. Load all weights
2. Retrieve loaded weight names and store them in `file_layer_names` (list)
3. Retrieve *current model* weight names and store them in `model_layer_names` (list)
4. Iterate over `file_layer_names` as `name`; if `name` is in `model_layer_names`, append loaded weight with that name to `weight_values_to_load`
5. Assign weights in `weight_values_to_load` to model using `K.batch_set_value`

Note that this requires you to *name* every layer in both AE and decoder models and make them match. It's possible to rewrite this code to brute-force assign sequentially in a `try-except` loop, but that's both inefficient and bug-prone.

---

**Usage**:

```py
## omitted; use code as in question but name all ## DECODER layers as below
autoencoder.save_weights('autoencoder_weights.h5')

## DECODER (independent)
decoder_input = Input(batch_shape=K.int_shape(x))
y = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh',padding='valid',name='decod_conv1d_1')(decoder_input)
y = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_1')(y)
y = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_2')(y)
y = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_2')(y)
y = Flatten(name='decod_flatten')(y)
y = Dense(501, name='decod_dense1')(y)
decoded = Reshape((501,1), name='decod_reshape')(y)

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoded)
decoder.save_weights('decoder_weights.h5')

load_weights(decoder, 'autoencoder_weights.h5')
```

---

**Function:**

```py
import h5py
import keras.backend as K

def load_weights(model, filepath):
    with h5py.File(filepath, mode='r') as f:
        file_layer_names = [n.decode('utf8') for n in f.attrs['layer_names']]
        model_layer_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]

        weight_values_to_load = []
        for name in file_layer_names:
            if name not in model_layer_names:
                print(name, "is ignored; skipping")
                continue
            g = f[name]
            weight_names = [n.decode('utf8') for n in g.attrs['weight_names']]

            weight_values = []
            if len(weight_names) != 0:
                weight_values = [g[weight_name] for weight_name in weight_names]
            try:
                layer = model.get_layer(name=name)
            except:
                layer = None
            if layer is not None:
                symbolic_weights = (layer.trainable_weights + 
                                    layer.non_trainable_weights)
                if len(symbolic_weights) != len(weight_values):
                    print('Model & file weights shapes mismatch')
                else:
                    weight_values_to_load += zip(symbolic_weights, weight_values)

        K.batch_set_value(weight_values_to_load)
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it and I got
`(u'conv1d', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'max_pooling1d', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'conv1d_1', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'max_pooling1d_1', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'flatten', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'dense', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'reshape', 'is ignored; skipping')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Read.py", line 66, in <module>
    load_weights(decoder, 'autoencoder_weights.h5')`

Comment: `File "Read.py", line 50, in load_weights
    K.batch_set_value(weight_values_to_load)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2725, in batch_set_value
    assign_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf_dtype, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'placeholder'`

Comment: also let me ask: are we sure that this way, `encoded` are both the final output of my encoder AND the input of my decoder? I think I may need to modify the architecture to accomplish this: so far, the last layer of the encoder CONNECTED to the decoder is a `MaxPooling1D`, whereas I would like a `dense`

Comment: @johnhenry As-is, there is no explicit encoder - but defining it is simple: `Model(encoder_input, encoded)` (though I'd recommend the final layer be learnable, e.g. `Dense`). As for "input to your decoder", you cannot directly connect the encoder output as decoder input, as that brings you back to your original AE; the `Input` layer is used instead where you feed encoder outs as "data" (though you _can_ set it up so encoder feeds decoder, e.g. `encoder_outs = encoder.predict(x) -- decoder_outs = decoder.predict(encoder_outs)`. Also, post your error trace in the original question

Comment: sorry but if `decoder_input = Input(batch_shape=K.int_shape(x))' how can I feed `encoder_outs` to the standalone decoder? `encoder_outs` is going to have shape `(None, 32)`, whereas x as shape `(None, 123, 32)`

Comment: @johnhenry Right, you'll need to change it to `K.int_shape(encoded)` - my code is per your original AE, whereas now you've changed the defined "encoder" in relation to "decoder". As a debug tip, run `for layer in model.layers: print(K.int_shape(layer.output))` to see outs shapes - and adjust accordingly