# Why do predictions differ for Autoencoder vs. Encoder + Decoder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I build a CNN 1d Autoencoder in Keras, following the advice [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603328/how-do-i-split-an-convolutional-autoencoder?rq=1), where Encoder and Decoder are separated. My goal is to re-use the decoder, once the Autoencoder has been trained. The central layer of my Autoencoder is a `Dense` layer, because I would like to learn it afterwards.

My problem is that if I compile and fit the whole Autoencoder, written as `Decoder()Encoder()(x)` where `x` is the input, I get a different prediction when I do

autoencoder.predict(training_set)

w.r.t. if I first encode the training set in a set of central features, and then let the decoder decode them. These two approaches should give identical answers, once the Autoencoder has been trained.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Lambda, Activation, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, UpSampling1D, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GaussianNoise
import keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Add

import tensorflow as tf

import scipy.io
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import copy


training = # some training set, 1500 samples of 501 point each
testing = # some testing set, 500 samples of 501 point each

# reshaping for CNN
training = np.reshape(training, [1500, 501, 1])
testing = np.reshape(testing, [500, 501, 1])


# normalize input
X_mean = training.mean()
oscillations -= X_mean
X_std = training.std()
training /= X_std


copy_of_test = copy.copy(testing)
testing -= X_mean
testing /= X_std

### MODEL ###

def Encoder():
    encoder_input = Input(batch_shape=(None, 501, 1))  
    e1 = Conv1D(256,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(encoder_input)
    e2 = MaxPooling1D(2)(e1)
    e3 = Conv1D(32,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(e2)
    e4 = MaxPooling1D(2)(e3)
    e5 = Flatten()(e4)
    encoded = Dense(32,activation = 'tanh')(e5)
    return Model(encoder_input, encoded)


def Decoder():
    encoded_input = Input(shape=(32,))  
    encoded_reshaped = Reshape((32,1))(encoded_input)
    d1 = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_1')(encoded_reshaped)
    d2 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_1')(d1)
    d3 = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_2')(d2)
    d4 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_2')(d3)
    d5 = Flatten(name='decod_flatten')(d4)
    d6 = Dense(501, name='decod_dense1')(d5)
    decoded = Reshape((501,1), name='decod_reshape')(d6)
    return Model(encoded_input, decoded)


# define input to the model:
x = Input(batch_shape=(None, 501, 1))
y = Input(shape=(32,))

# make the model:
autoencoder = Model(x, Decoder()(Encoder()(x)))

# compile the model:
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
for layer in autoencoder.layers: print(K.int_shape(layer.output))


epochs = 100
batch_size = 100
validation_split = 0.2
# train the model
history = autoencoder.fit(x = training, y = training,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_split=validation_split)

# Encoder
encoder = Model(inputs=x, outputs=Encoder()(x), name='encoder')
print('enc:')
for layer in encoder.layers: print(K.int_shape(layer.output))
features = encoder.predict(training) # features

# Decoder
decoder = Model(inputs=y, outputs=Decoder()(y), name='decoder')
print('dec:')
for layer in decoder.layers: print(K.int_shape(layer.output))
score = decoder.predict(features) # 
score = np.squeeze(score)    

predictions = autoencoder.predict(training)
predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)

# plotting one random case
# score should be equal to predictions!
# because score is obtained from the trained decoder acting on the encoded features, while predictions are obtained form the Autoencoder acting on the training set 
plt.plot(score[100], label='eD')
plt.plot(predictions[100], label='AE')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

**EDIT** following OverLordGoldDragon's answer:

I implemented the suggestion in the answer, writing the following in the same file:

```
def reset_seeds():
    np.random.seed(1)
    random.seed(2)
    if tf.__version__[0] == '2':
        tf.random.set_seed(3)
    else:
        tf.set_random_seed(3)
    print("RANDOM SEEDS RESET")


def Encoder():
    encoder_input = Input(batch_shape=(None, 501, 1))  
    e1 = Conv1D(256,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(encoder_input)
    e2 = MaxPooling1D(2)(e1)
    e3 = Conv1D(32,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(e2)
    e4 = MaxPooling1D(2)(e3)
    e5 = Flatten()(e4)
    encoded = Dense(32,activation = 'tanh')(e5)
    encoded = Reshape((32,1))(encoded)
    return Model(encoder_input, encoded)


def Decoder():
    encoded_input = Input(shape=(32,))  
    encoded_reshaped = Reshape((32,1))(encoded_input)
    d1 = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_1')(encoded_reshaped)
    d2 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_1')(d1)
    d3 = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_2')(d2)
    d4 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_2')(d3)
    d5 = Flatten(name='decod_flatten')(d4)
    d6 = Dense(501, name='decod_dense1')(d5)
    decoded = Reshape((501,1), name='decod_reshape')(d6)
    return Model(encoded_input, decoded)


def DecoderAE(encoder_input, encoded_input):
    encoded_reshaped = Reshape((32,1))(encoded_input)
    d1 = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid',
                       name='decod_conv1d_1')(encoded_reshaped)
    d2 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_1')(d1)
    d3 = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_2')(d2)
    d4 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_2')(d3)
    d5 = Flatten(name='decod_flatten')(d4)
    d6 = Dense(501, name='decod_dense1')(d5)
    decoded = Reshape((501,1), name='decod_reshape')(d6)
    return Model(encoder_input, decoded)


def load_weights(model, filepath):
    with h5py.File(filepath, mode='r') as f:
        file_layer_names = [n.decode('utf8') for n in f.attrs['layer_names']]
        model_layer_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]

        weight_values_to_load = []
        for name in file_layer_names:
            if name not in model_layer_names:
                print(name, "is ignored; skipping")
                continue
            g = f[name]
            weight_names = [n.decode('utf8') for n in g.attrs['weight_names']]

            weight_values = []
            if len(weight_names) != 0:
                weight_values = [g[weight_name] for weight_name in weight_names]
            try:
                layer = model.get_layer(name=name)
            except:
                layer = None
            if layer is not None:
                symbolic_weights = (layer.trainable_weights + 
                                    layer.non_trainable_weights)
                if len(symbolic_weights) != len(weight_values):
                    print('Model & file weights shapes mismatch')
                else:
                    weight_values_to_load += zip(symbolic_weights, weight_values)

        K.batch_set_value(weight_values_to_load)


X = np.random.randn(10, 501, 1)
reset_seeds()
encoder = Encoder()
AE = DecoderAE(encoder.input, encoder.output)
AE.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')


epochs = 10
batch_size = 100
validation_split = 0.2
# train the model
history = AE.fit(x = training, y = training,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_split=validation_split)


reset_seeds()
encoder = Encoder()
decoder = Decoder()

# Test equality
features = encoder.predict(X)
features = np.squeeze(features) # had to add this otherwise it would complain because of wrong shapes
score = decoder.predict(features) 
predictions = AE.predict(X)
print(np.sum(score - predictions))
# I am actually getting values >> 1


AE.save_weights('autoencoder_weights.h5')
AE_saved_weights = AE.get_weights()

decoder = Decoder()
load_weights(decoder, 'autoencoder_weights.h5')  # see "reference"
decoder_loaded_weights = decoder.get_weights()

AE_decoder_weights = AE_saved_weights[-len(decoder_loaded_weights):]
for w1, w2 in zip(AE_decoder_weights, decoder_loaded_weights):
    print(np.sum(w1 - w2))
```

The code runs training the AE, however

1) I get values >>1 for the difference between `score` and `predictions`

2) the code stops producing

```
(u'input_1', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'conv1d', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'max_pooling1d', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'conv1d_1', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'max_pooling1d_1', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'flatten', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'dense', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'reshape', 'is ignored; skipping')
(u'reshape_1', 'is ignored; skipping')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Autoenc.py", line 256, in <module>
    load_weights(decoder, 'autoencoder_weights.h5')  # see "reference"
  File "Autoenc.py", line 219, in load_weights
    K.batch_set_value(weight_values_to_load)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2725, in batch_set_value
    assign_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf_dtype,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

**2 EDIT**

Here is my new file following last comment by @OverLordGoldDragon .
I get the error posted below.

```
def reset_seeds():
    np.random.seed(1)
    random.seed(2)
    if tf.__version__[0] == '2':
        tf.random.set_seed(3)
    else:
        tf.set_random_seed(3)
    print("RANDOM SEEDS RESET")


def Encoder():
    encoder_input = Input(batch_shape=(None, 501, 1))  
    e1 = Conv1D(256,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(encoder_input)
    e2 = MaxPooling1D(2)(e1)
    e3 = Conv1D(32,3, activation='tanh', padding='valid')(e2)
    e4 = MaxPooling1D(2)(e3)
    e5 = Flatten()(e4)
    encoded = Dense(32,activation = 'tanh')(e5)
    encoded = Reshape((32,1))(encoded)
    return Model(encoder_input, encoded)


def Decoder():
    encoded_input = Input(shape=(32,))  
    encoded_reshaped = Reshape((32,1))(encoded_input)
    d1 = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_1')(encoded_reshaped)
    d2 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_1')(d1)
    d3 = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_2')(d2)
    d4 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_2')(d3)
    d5 = Flatten(name='decod_flatten')(d4)
    d6 = Dense(501, name='decod_dense1')(d5)
    decoded = Reshape((501,1), name='decod_reshape')(d6)
    return Model(encoded_input, decoded)


def DecoderAE(encoder_input, encoded_input):
    encoded_reshaped = Reshape((32,1))(encoded_input)
    d1 = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid',
                       name='decod_conv1d_1')(encoded_reshaped)
    d2 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_1')(d1)
    d3 = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_2')(d2)
    d4 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_2')(d3)
    d5 = Flatten(name='decod_flatten')(d4)
    d6 = Dense(501, name='decod_dense1')(d5)
    decoded = Reshape((501,1), name='decod_reshape')(d6)
    return Model(encoder_input, decoded)


def load_weights(model, filepath):
    with h5py.File(filepath, mode='r') as f:
        file_layer_names = [n.decode('utf8') for n in f.attrs['layer_names']]
        model_layer_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]

        weight_values_to_load = []
        for name in file_layer_names:
            if name not in model_layer_names:
                print(name, "is ignored; skipping")
                continue
            g = f[name]
            weight_names = [n.decode('utf8') for n in g.attrs['weight_names']]

            weight_values = []
            if len(weight_names) != 0:
                weight_values = [g[weight_name] for weight_name in weight_names]
            try:
                layer = model.get_layer(name=name)
            except:
                layer = None
            if layer is not None:
                symbolic_weights = (layer.trainable_weights + 
                                    layer.non_trainable_weights)
                if len(symbolic_weights) != len(weight_values):
                    print('Model & file weights shapes mismatch')
                else:
                    weight_values_to_load += zip(symbolic_weights, weight_values)

        K.batch_set_value(weight_values_to_load)


X = np.random.randn(10, 501, 1)
reset_seeds()
encoder = Encoder()
AE = DecoderAE(encoder.input, encoder.output)
AE.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')


epochs = 2
batch_size = 100
validation_split = 0.2
# train the model
history = AE.fit(x = training, y = training,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_split=validation_split)


reset_seeds()
encoder = Encoder()
decoder = Decoder()
decoder.save_weights('decoder_weights.h5')



AE.save_weights('autoencoder_weights.h5')
AE_saved_weights = AE.get_weights()

decoder = Decoder()
load_weights(decoder, 'autoencoder_weights.h5')  # see "reference"
decoder_loaded_weights = decoder.get_weights()

# Test equality
features = encoder.predict(X)
features = np.squeeze(features) 
score = decoder.predict(features) 
predictions = AE.predict(X)
print(np.sum(score - predictions))


AE_decoder_weights = AE_saved_weights[-len(decoder_loaded_weights):]
for w1, w2 in zip(AE_decoder_weights, decoder_loaded_weights):
    print(np.sum(w1 - w2))



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Autoenc_pazzo.py", line 251, in <module>
    decoder_loaded_weights = decoder.get_weights()
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 153, in get_weights
    return super(Model, self).get_weights()
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1130, in get_weights
    return backend.batch_get_value(params)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3010, in batch_get_value
    return get_session(tensors).run(tensors)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable decod_conv1d_1_2/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/decod_conv1d_1_2/bias/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
     [[node decod_conv1d_1_2/bias/Read/ReadVariableOp (defined at Autoenc_pazzo.py:168) ]]

Original stack trace for u'decod_conv1d_1_2/bias/Read/ReadVariableOp':
  File "Autoenc_pazzo.py", line 249, in <module>
    decoder = Decoder()
  File "Autoenc_pazzo.py", line 168, in Decoder
    d1 = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_1')(encoded_reshaped)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 591, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1881, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 174, in build
    dtype=self.dtype)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 384, in add_weight
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 663, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
    **kwargs_for_getter)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 155, in make_variable
    shape=variable_shape if variable_shape.rank else None)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 259, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 220, in _variable_v1_call
    shape=shape)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 198, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2495, in default_variable_creator
    shape=shape)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 263, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 460, in __init__
    shape=shape)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 649, in _init_from_args
    value = self._read_variable_op()
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 935, in _read_variable_op
    self._dtype)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_resource_variable_ops.py", line 587, in read_variable_op
    "ReadVariableOp", resource=resource, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon

Comment: @MegaNightdude maybe you know the answer

Comment: The problem here is rather tricky, and has nothing to do with autoencoders - though your AE code is off regardless. It is, however, bad practice to jump related questions without giving proper feedback on ones answered (esp. if asking the answerer again). I got the predictions to agree 100% - if you'd like me to show you how, let's finish your earlier question first. P.S., '@' doesn't work on questions a user hasn't participated in - I stumbled on this question independently.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon apologies. I edited my quetion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364974/how-to-load-trained-autoencoder-weights-for-decoder to give you feedback on your procedure, which I implemented. It looks now as if the saved decoder does not produce the same output as the full autoencoder, once given the encoded features. In general, I would really appreciate if you could also tell me why my AE code is off regardless. Thanks

Comment: The best test of saving/loading a model is to assign model weights to a variable before saving, then same to another variable after loading, and subtract to compare; if you see the sum of differences is 0 (or close per roundoffs), the code works and the previous question is resolved. I'll answer this current question, but the previous one shouldn't be abandoned (i.e. not accepted)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I accepted yor answer on the other question thanks. Please let me know about this one

Answer (score 0):

Main problem with your code: lack of use of a random seed. I refer to full explanation to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210700/are-these-models-equivalent/58210853#58210853), and focus on your particular instance here.

---

**Explanation**:

- Order of model instantiation matters, as it changes the initialized weights
- In usage, if you *train* multiple models, you should reset seed both at model instantiation *and* before training
- Your AE, Encoder, and Decoder definitions make a redundant use of `Input`, and complicate introspection (e.g. `.summary()`); `Encoder()` and `Decoder()` already take care of it
- To check whether loaded decoder weights match saved trained AE decoder weights, see example below

---

**SOLUTION**:

```py
reset_seeds()
X = np.random.randn(10, 501, 1)  # '10' arbitrary
encoder_input = Input(batch_shape=(None, 501, 1))

reset_seeds()
encoder = Encoder()
decoder = Decoder()
autoencoder = Model(x, decoder(encoder(x)))
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

reset_seeds()
encoder = Encoder()
decoder = Decoder()
```

```py
predictions = autoencoder.predict(X)

features = encoder.predict(X)
score = decoder.predict(features)

print(np.sum(score - predictions))
# 0.0  <-- 100% agreement
```

---

**Save/load example** + preferred AE definition; [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364974/how-to-load-trained-autoencoder-weights-for-decoder/58365284#58365284)

Your AE definition limits introspection via e.g. `.summary()`; instead, define as below.

```py
X = np.random.randn(10, 501, 1)
reset_seeds()
encoder = Encoder()
AE = DecoderAE(encoder.input, encoder.output)
AE.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

reset_seeds()
encoder = Encoder()
decoder = Decoder()

# Test equality
features = encoder.predict(X)
score = decoder.predict(features) 
predictions = AE.predict(X)
print(np.sum(score - predictions))
# 0.0  <-- exact or close to
```

```py
AE.save_weights('autoencoder_weights.h5')
AE_saved_weights = AE.get_weights()

decoder = Decoder()
load_weights(decoder, 'autoencoder_weights.h5')  # see "reference"
decoder_loaded_weights = decoder.get_weights()

AE_decoder_weights = AE_saved_weights[-len(decoder_loaded_weights):]
for w1, w2 in zip(AE_decoder_weights, decoder_loaded_weights):
    print(np.sum(w1 - w2))
# 0.0
# 0.0
# ...
```

---

**Functions used:**

```py
def reset_seeds():
    np.random.seed(1)
    random.seed(2)
    if tf.__version__[0] == '2':
        tf.random.set_seed(3)
    else:
        tf.set_random_seed(3)
    print("RANDOM SEEDS RESET")

def DecoderAE(encoder_input, encoded_input):
    encoded_reshaped = Reshape((32,1))(encoded_input)
    d1 = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid',
                       name='decod_conv1d_1')(encoded_reshaped)
    d2 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_1')(d1)
    d3 = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='tanh', padding='valid', name='decod_conv1d_2')(d2)
    d4 = UpSampling1D(2, name='decod_upsampling1d_2')(d3)
    d5 = Flatten(name='decod_flatten')(d4)
    d6 = Dense(501, name='decod_dense1')(d5)
    decoded = Reshape((501,1), name='decod_reshape')(d6)
    return Model(encoder_input, decoded)
```

Comment: I am happy and ready to accept your answer, thanks very much. I am getting different `scores` and `predictions`; see my edit to my question.

Comment: @johnhenry If you aren't seeing intended behavior with my code, the question isn't 'answered', no worries. The problem is, you're running `encoder.predict` and `decoder.predict` _without_ first loading the weights - thus comparing their predictions against the _trained_ `AE`. Also, don't know what's causing the error - which (1) TensorFlow, (2) Keras, and (3) Python version are you using? And is there any code other than what you provided?

Comment: Thanks I solved the second issue by downgrading from Tensorflow 2 to 1.14. Now I have the issue that, when using the function `load_weights`, it seems as if the weights for the decoder cannot be found, see last edit to my question. Please comment on the exact order of steps to follow; I suspect I am not following the right order

Comment: @johnhenry Are you sure it isn't finding the _decoder_ weights? Your output log shows that it's precisely ignoring the _encoder_ weights. Try copy-pasting my answer's code exactly and see if it works - can adapt as needed afterwards. Let me know if issues persist

Comment: @johnhenry Yeah, this definitely looks like a bad install - try steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58053509/why-does-my-keras-model-train-after-i-load-it-even-though-i-have-not-actually-s/58160270#58160270). The code I provided works on a correct install, and you'll likely save lots of time reinstalling vs. debugging the problem. As a tip, upgrade to Python 3.6+, and 3.7 even comes with fixed-order dictionaries.

Comment: does the code I pasted in my 2 edit work for you? Could you kindly provide an answer with a full list of all the steps (including definitions etc) to copy-paste? Thanks and sorry, I think I got lost between the various versions

Comment: @johnhenry Yes, it works perfectly (minus predictions agreement for described reasons), and loaded weights agree 100% - my specs [here](https://puu.sh/EswrG/ced8e201d6.png)